# let in strange behavior

Tags: haskell, let

I have the following program:

```
mnr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]  :: [Int]
name = "Max Mustermann" :: String
kzn = "e53X" :: String

t1 = ("p1",(take 2.tail)mnr, (take 3.words.(let no n= name;in no))"No");
{-result: t1 == ("p1",[1,2],["Max","Mustermann"]) -}
```

Why is "No" ignored and what does `let no n= name;in no` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty crazily written code. Let's try to resolve it piece by piece.

First of all, `t1` is a tuple of type `(a,b,c)`. Let's write `t1 = (x,y,z)` and try to figure things out. It's pretty clear that `a` is `String`, and `x` is `"p1"`.

The second component is `((take 2) . tail) mnr`, which is `take 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, which is `[1,2]`. So `b` is `[Int]`, and `y` is `[1,2]`. Makes sense.

The third component is oddly written. First of all,

```
let no n = name in no
```

simply defines a function `\n -> name`, i.e. the constant function returning `name`. This is much more nicely written as `const name`. So you have the composition `(take 3) . words . (const name)`, and you apply it to `"No"`. Well, `(const name) "No"` is obviously just `name`, i.e. `"Max Mustermann"`. So `words` applied to this is  `["Max", "Mustermann"]`, and then `take 3` gets you the first three elements, which is again `["Max", "Mustermann"]`. That's `z` above, and shows that `c` is `[String]`.

All in all, you end up with `t1` having type `(String, [Int], [String])`, and value `("p1", [1,2], ["Max", "Mustermann"])`.

---

The code for the third component should be cleaned up, but how you clean it up depends on what you really want to do onwards. As it stands now, however, it's very convoluted and will just confuse you and others.

Comment: Whoever set this exam is pretty sadistic.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: ... and has strange ideas of what should be tested in students.

Comment: @gspr Why is it strange to expect students to be able to apply the definitions of simple functions and standard language constructs in a small example? True, this is a contrived program, and code you normally wouldn't and shouldn't write like this. Still, this doesn't mean that you shouldn't be able to understand it.

Comment: @kosmikus: Yeah, you're probably right. I guess my aversion comes from the mix of "real-world looking" code and trip-ups like writing `x` as `const x undefined`. But I do agree with you, when I think about it :)